# Show and hide text using onclick and oncontextmenu simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I show context menu in my table using oncontextmenu in **tr** tag and onclick for my button inside **tr** tag. But I don't know how to hide menu using onclick in any area?

I added `window.onclick = hideContextMenu` as global variable and after that button can't show my context menu.

```js
window.onkeydown = listenKeys;
var contextMenu = document.getElementById("contextMenu");

function showContextMenu(event) {

        contextMenu.style.display = 'block';
        contextMenu.style.left = event.clientX+ 'px';
        contextMenu.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    return false;
}

function hideContextMenu() {
    contextMenu.style.display = 'none';
}

function listenKeys(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

    if (keyCode === 27){
        hideContextMenu();
    }
}
```

```css
html, body, .container{
    height: 100%;
   
}
button {
 background: blue;
 height:50px; width:50px;
}
.context-menu{
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #ccc;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 background: #eee;
}

.context-menu a {
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>
      <th scope="col">Second name</th>
      <th scope="col"> </th>
      <th scope="col"> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr oncontextmenu="return showContextMenu(event);">
        <th scope="row">01.01.2001</th>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Cole</td>
        <td>
          <div class="container" >
            <div id="contextMenu" class="context-menu">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#one">One</a>
                    <a href="#two">Two</a>
                    <a href="#three">Three</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button onclick="return showContextMenu(event)"> 
          <div class="container" >
              <div id="contextMenu" class="context-menu">
                  <ul>
                      <a href="#one">One</a>
                      <a href="#two">Two</a>
                      <a href="#three">Three</a>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          </button>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to show menu always using `oncontextmenu` in all **tr** tag. Show menu after `onclick` press button. And hide context menu I want in any part table